# chrome.notifications.update() or create()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want my chrome extension to take a `notification.id`, and:

1. Update an existing notification if it does exist.
   OR
2. Create a new notification if it doesn't exist.

Calling `clear()` then `create()` is not ideal, since the animation is visually jarring for both `remove()` and `create()` methods, where I want to update without animations. Plus, obviously, calling `update()` on a disappeared notification doesn't do anything.

Is there an easy way to implement this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:** This approach no longer works on any platform except ChromeOS due to the removal of Chrome's Notification Center.

Possible ideas to work around it include using `requireInteraction: true` flag on notifications to fully control notification lifetime.

---

There is a dirty trick for re-showing a notification. If you change a notification's priority to a higher value, it will be re-shown if it exists.

```
function createOrUpdate(id, options, callback) {
  // Try to lower priority to minimal "shown" priority
  chrome.notifications.update(id, {priority: 0}, function(existed) {
    if(existed) {
      var targetPriority = options.priority || 0;
      options.priority = 1;
      // Update with higher priority
      chrome.notifications.update(id, options, function() {
        chrome.notifications.update(id, {priority: targetPriority}, function() {
          callback(true); // Updated
        });
      });
    } else {
      chrome.notifications.create(id, options, function() {
        callback(false); // Created
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: @aakashjain I would think it doesn't (except on ChromeOS) because the notification center was removed. A new solution is needed indeed.

Comment: I don't think there's any solution on OSes without a notification center. The only solution I could come up with involves showing a new notification every time.

Comment: @aakashjain What is currently happening if you try to update a timed out notification? Does `existed` still report true? Also, there's a solution involving `requireInteraction` - that puts you in control of the notification lifetime.

Comment: `existed` does report true for timed out notifications, but the notification isn't shown again even if you go through the priority update as in your answer. I know that `requireInteraction` prevents the notification from being automatically dismissed but that's usually not the kind of notification I want to show.

Comment: I would say that `existed == true` after removing the notification center is a report-worthy bug.

Answer (score 2):

[Xan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26358154/3441882) no longer works on Windows, MacOS, or Linux. At this point the only way to make sure your notification displays, no matter what, is to create a new notification.

If you want to prevent multiple notifications from being on screen, you'll have to clear the old notification and replace it with a new one. This is demonstrated below.

```
NOTIFICATION_ID = "some_random_string";
function showNotification ( ... , callback) {
    chrome.notifications.clear(NOTIFICATION_ID, function(cleared) {
        var options = {
            // whatever
        };
        chrome.notifications.create(NOTIFICATION_ID, options, callback);
    });
}
```

Of course, this results in an animation of existing notification getting dismissed and a new notification immediately taking its place, but unfortunately this is unavoidable.