# Chrome Extension notifications not showing contextMessage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my code, the contextMessage is not showing up
I know it works fine with `chrome.notifications.create`, but if I use that then I can't make it so the notification never disappears without being closed or clicked on

```
function Notify(Title, Body, miniMsg, Url, Icon) {
    var notification = new Notification(Title, {
        icon: Icon||"Logo.png",
        body: Body,
        contextMessage:miniMsg
    });
    notification.onclick = function () {
        window.open(Url);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple: Compatibility.

You are trying to use a feature that isn't supported in Chrome without the `webkit` prefix, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification#Browser_compatibility). For a Google Chrome extension, it is suggested to use the [`chrome.notifications` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications).

Using the `chrome.notifications` API, you are unable to specify how long the notifications stay open. However, another option is to use the `chrome.experimental.notifications` API, which would prevent you from publishing your extension to the webstore, and has very little documentation.

You could also change the `priority` option in `chrome.notifications.create` to any integer between -2 to 2, where 2 is the highest, and would grant your notification the most display time.

Since you seem to be using the `Notifications` object, you might notice that your syntax does not match that shown in the MDN documentation. Primarily, there does not seem to be any `contextMessage` parameter for Notifications. As a side note, the `onclick` callback won't work, since the `Url` parameter is no longer executed in the current scope. The anonymous function will not be able to see the `Url` parameter passed into `Notify`. You also might want to check out [compatibility and notes for Notifications](http://caniuse.com/#search=Notification).

Comment: The first half of this answer is incorrect. The standard `Notification` constructor *is* supported in Chrome. `webkitNotifications` went away a while back. `chrome.experimental.notifications` no longer exists, it has been moved to the [`chrome.notifications`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications) namespace.

Comment: Also note the [priority update trick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350747/chrome-notifications-update-or-create). If you do this on an interval, it will keep your notification shown.

Comment: @RobW, thanks for the correction. Upon further research, I realized that that was correct. However, the new `chrome.notifications` API does not support many of the rich notification features that `chrome.experimental.notifications` was supposed to allow. @Xan, that's a pretty neat trick. Thanks for letting us know!