# Subsequent Chrome extension notifications onAlarm never displayed again if user doesn't interact with current one

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, notifications

I'm writing a Chrome extension that reminds the user of something every X minutes, using [event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages), [alarms](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms), and the [Chrome extensions notifications API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications).

The problem is that if the user lets the notification window disappear (it's on screen for only ~10 seconds), it will never be displayed again. This seems like a bug in Chrome, but wanted to check if maybe I'm missing something.

```
chrome.alarms.create('remindUser', {
  delayInMinutes: 1,
  periodInMinutes: 5
});

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function (alarm) {
  chrome.notifications.create(alarm.name, {
    type: 'basic',
    title: 'Reminder',
    message: '...',
    buttons: [
      { title: 'Act on it' },
      { title: 'Later' }
    ]
  }, function callback(notificationId) {
    // nothing necessary here, but required before Chrome 42
    console.log(notificationId, 'notifications ARE called repeatedly, but the window is not displayed');
  });
});
```

Nothing special in `manifest.json`:

```
"permissions": ["alarms", "notifications", "storage", "contextMenus"]
```

If I click on the `x` button to close the notification, it will be displayed next time. But if I'm away from the computer and don't do anything when the notification shows up, it will never be displayed again. The console shows the `remindUser notifications ARE called repeatedly [...]` message with an increasing count, but the notification is not displayed again.

How can this be fixed? I'd rather not use the [`Notification` API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example/13328513#13328513) because it bugs the user for permission.

Comment: I wonder if this could be a restriction added by Google, to prevent applications from repeatedly annoying the user (similar to "prevent this page from creating additional dialogs").

Comment: @Johnny_Rose: [alarms are already limited](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms) to at most once per minute. I think it's an oversight similar to the [Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=875114). I filed a [Chromium bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=493500).

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is that the notifications always have the same ID, `alarm.name`. This causes subsequent notifications to replace previous ones as indicated at 
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications#method-create

After removing the ID from the `chrome.notifications.create` call, all notifications are displayed. There is still the issue that they'll be hidden under Chrome's bell icon in the system tray though, while notifications generated with the Notification API never disappear:

[image]

Not sure what the reason is for the inconsistency between the two notification APIs in how persistence/docking into the system tray are handled, so I filed a [bug with Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=493500).

Comment: This is expected; bug will probably be closed as Wontfix. From the ground up Chrome notifications are designed not to stay on the screen for too long. Do note, there is a hacky way to bypass this - if your update changes priority, it will be re-shown. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26358154/934239).

Comment: @Xan - you can trivially create notifications that stay on the screen indefinitely by using [the Notification API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example/13328513#13328513).

Comment: I know, and I know you know it. I'm talking specifically about Rich Notifications.