# chrome.notifications.create(msgID, msg) not showing multiple Messages on Windows OS

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am calling chrome.notifications.create(msgID, msg), multiple times, each time with different msgID. For example if I have 5 messages to User, I call the chrome.notifications.create(msgID, msg) 5 times. It works perfectly fine on Apple MacBook where it stacks the pop-up windows on one above other. However on Windows 10, it shows just one pop-up window and only after closing the first pop-up it shows second one and so on so forth.

How can I achieve same experience as MacBook on Windows 10?
[image: MacBook]

[image: Windows 10]

Comment: I think this is browser specific and not dependent on OS

Comment: In both cases its same Chrome Browser version, so  I think its how OS renders it.

Comment: Did you refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350747/chrome-notifications-update-or-create. Some OS related create() issues are mentioned there.

Comment: Sounds like something Windows 10 does intentionally to reduce the cognitive load on the user.